# Keep same Datetime format while reading from JSON in C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a JSON content like this

```
"started_on": "2017-12-01",
"start_time": "2017-12-01T10:00:00+00:00",
"finish_time": "2017-12-01T11:00:00+00:00",
```

I want to read the start time and end time as a string in same format and i tried  the below code for doing the same

```
 JObject _task = JObject.Parse(response_json);
 string _description = "\n start_time:" + (string)_task["start_time"];
 _description += "\n finish_time:" + (string)_task["finish_time"];
```

This reads from JSON correctly , but when i check the datetime format i can see this as like "12/01/2017" only.
How can i keep the same format while doing the conversion and i want the text as it is in the JSON parameter

Answer (score 2):

You need to instruct JSON.NET to [read them as strings](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_DateParseHandling.htm):

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None
};
JObject _task = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(response_json, settings);
```

If you need to get some of the values as `DateTime` objects after they have all been read as strings, you can use this:

```
var dt = _task["property"].Value<DateTime>();
```

Although at this stage you may just want to create a class to represent your JSON:

```
public class MyTask
{
    public DateTime Property1 {get;set;} // property1 will be read as a DateTime
    public string Property2 {get;set;} // property2 will be read as a string
}
MyTask _task = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyTask>(response_json);
```

Comment: can we set this on a property level. Since some other datetimes , i have to read the way it is now

Comment: @Jbin If you create a class to represent your JSON, you can choose between `string` and `DateTime` for the property type accordingly. Alternatively, you can call `_task["propertyIWantAsDate"].Value<DateTime>()` to convert the string into a `DateTime` for the properties where you need that.